# React - How to stay on the same page even if it was refreshed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-router

I'm using react-router for the link to the different pages. Everything works fine, however, once I'll refresh the page, it'll go to the login page for a moment and it'll go back to the homepage. It was even worse if I'll go to the admin page, refreshing the page will direct the user to the login page, however, the user is still logged in and only displays the login page. I'm also using Firebase Firestore and firebase authentication.

app.js

```
const App = (props) => {
  const { setCurrentUser, currentUser } = props;
  const admin = checkUserAdmin(currentUser);
  console.log(admin);

  useEffect(() => {
    const authListener = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await handleUserProfile(userAuth);
        userRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          setCurrentUser({
            id: snapshot.id,
            ...snapshot.data(),
          });
        });
      }

      setCurrentUser(userAuth);
    });

    return () => {
      authListener();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
     
        <Route
          exact
          path="/login"
          render={() => (
            <MainLayout>
              <LoginPage />
            </MainLayout>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/profile"
          render={() => (
            <WithAuth>
              <MainLayout>
                <ProfilePage />
              </MainLayout>
            </WithAuth>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/admin"
          render={() => (
            <WithAdmin>
              <AdminHome />
            </WithAdmin>
          )}
        />
      
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

withAuth - restricting the users for the pages. If currentUser is a guest user, it directs the user to the login page.

```
import { useAuth } from "./../custom-hooks";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const WithAuth = (props) => useAuth(props) && props.children;

export default withRouter(WithAuth);
```

useAuth -  restricting the users for the pages. If currentUser is a guest user, it directs the user to the login page.

```
const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const useAuth = (props) => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector(mapState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      props.history.push("/login");
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  return currentUser;
};

export default useAuth;
```

withAdmin - pages only accessible to the admin

```
import { useAdmin } from "../../custom-hooks";

const WithAdmin = (props) => useAdmin(props) && props.children;

export default WithAdmin;
```

useAdmin - pages only accessible to the admin. If user is not an admin, it directs the user to the login page.

```
const mapState = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const useAdmin = (props) => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector(mapState);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!checkUserAdmin(currentUser)) {
      history.push("/login");
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  return currentUser;
};

export default useAdmin;
```

Below is my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Reducers:
userTypes:

```
const userTypes = {
  SET_CURRENT_USER: "SET_CURRENT_USER",
};

export default userTypes;
```

userActions:

```
import userTypes from "./user.types";

export const setCurrentUser = (user) => ({
  type: userTypes.SET_CURRENT_USER,
  payload: user,
});
```

userReducer:

```
import userTypes from "./user.types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  currentUser: null,
};

const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case userTypes.SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentUser: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userReducer;
```

rootReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import userReducer from "./user/user.reducer";

export default combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
});
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";

import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";

export const middlewares = [logger];

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export default store;
```

checkUserAdmin.js

```
export const checkUserAdmin = (currentUser) => {
  if (!currentUser || !Array.isArray(currentUser.roles)) return false;
  const { roles } = currentUser;
  if (roles.includes("admin")) return true;

  return false;
};
```

From the App.js, I console.log(currentUser) and this is what is shows:
[image]

Comment: Just a minor, unrelated, point about naming conventions... with a name like `WithAdmin`, or any function with the `with-` prefix, one would expect that to be a Higher Order Component instead of a wrapper component. That being said, the issue you have is that your redux store lives in memory, so when the page is reloaded, so to is your app, and it may take a moment to repopulate your `user` state slice. In these cases you need to use a third "indeterminant", or pending, state to signify ***not*** one state or the other with regards to access.

Comment: I forgot to mention that yes, it was a higher order component. Those withAuth and withAdmin.

Comment: Sorry, I was pointing out that these ***are not*** HOCs, but that you've named them like they were.

Comment: Is there some way where I could fix it?

Comment: Can you add your `user` reducer code to your question? As I said, I think the solution here is to use a "pending" state to not immediately decide one way or the other if a user should access a resource or be bounced off a route.

Comment: I've updated the code. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding an `authPending` state to your `userReducer`, initially `true`, and also set/cleared when the firestore logic is handing user changes.

userReducer & actions

```
const userTypes = {
  SET_AUTH_PENDING: "SET_AUTH_PENDING",
  SET_CURRENT_USER: "SET_CURRENT_USER",
};

const setAuthPending = pending => ({
  type: userTypes.SET_AUTH_PENDING,
  payload: pending,
});

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  authPending: true,
  currentUser: null,
};

const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case userTypes.SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        authPending: false
        currentUser: action.payload,
      };

    case userTypes.SET_AUTH_PENDING:
      return {
        ...state,
        authPending: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

app.js

```
const App = (props) => {
  const {
    setAuthPending, // <-- access action
    setCurrentUser,
    currentUser
  } = props;

  const admin = checkUserAdmin(currentUser);
  console.log(admin);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      setAuthPending(true); // <-- start auth pending
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await handleUserProfile(userAuth);
        userRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          setCurrentUser({ // <-- will clear auth pending
            id: snapshot.id,
            ...snapshot.data(),
          });
        });
      } else { 
        setCurrentUser(null); // <-- clear user data and pending
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        ...
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => ({
  currentUser: user.currentUser,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setAuthPending, // <-- wrap action creator in call to dispatch
  setCurrentUser,
};
```

Hooks & Wrappers

For these I suggest abstracting the logic into custom `Route` components.

```
const AuthRoute = props => {
  const { authPending, currentUser } = useSelector(state => state.user);

  if (authPending) {
    return "Loading..."; // or maybe a loading spinner
  };

  return currentUser ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  );
};

const AdminRoute = props => {
  const { authPending, currentUser } = useSelector(state => state.user);

  if (authPending) {
    return "Loading..."; // or maybe a loading spinner
  };

  return checkUserAdmin(currentUser) ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  );
};
```

Then the routes become

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => (
      <MainLayout>
        <Homepage />
      </MainLayout>
    )}
  />
  <Route
    exact
    path="/login"
    render={() => (
      <MainLayout>
        <LoginPage />
      </MainLayout>
    )}
  />
  <AuthRoute
    exact
    path="/profile"
    render={() => (
      <MainLayout>
        <ProfilePage />
      </MainLayout>
    )}
  />
  <AdminRoute
    exact
    path="/admin"
    component={AdminHome}
  />
</Switch>
```

After this, you may want to look into persisting your redux state into localStorage, and repopulating your redux state from localStorage when you are instantiating the `store` (*the `preloadedState` parameter*) object when your app is loading. You can manage yourself or look into something like [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist).

Comment: I'm kind of getting an error wit setAuthPending in app.js, it says "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setAuthPending is not a function"

Comment: @AranyaDream Did you define the `setAuthPending` action creator ***and*** pass it in `mapDispatchToProps` in the `connect` HOC?

Comment: sorry, `setAuthPending` does work.  For the user, it does already work. For admin, I would need to set the redux-persist? Since, it does have the word 'loading'  when refreshed but it does take the user right at the login page.

Comment: @AranyaDream It might be something with what `checkUserAdmin` is doing. Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: @AranyaDream And you've fully verified that after getting a user that `currentUser.roles` is an array and has the "admin" role included in it? Can you share the `currentUser` object you are storing the in the reducer and see in the `AdminRoute` component? (`console.log({ currentUser })` in the body)?

Comment: I've edited the post so it has the picture of the console.log results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236177/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-aranya-dream).

Answer (score 0):

When a user login you can store some values about the user in localStorage,like username or a token or just a login ,

`localStorage.setItem(IS_LOGIN, true);`

After that you can use that in your userReducer, when you initiate state you can directly determine the user is login or not.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
 isLogin: localStorage.IS_LOGIN
};
```

now you can determine a user is login or not before the page load. If you wanna push user to the login page  you can use in useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLogin) {
      props.history.push("/login");
    }
  }, [isLogin]);

  return isLogin;
};
```

when your app first loaded there is no user information on the userReducer, because of that when page load you will be directing to the login page.